# Can't compile Lucene project with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, path, lucene, indexing

Here's my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.lucene.index.CorruptIndexException;

public class Main 
{
    public static void main()
    {
        //Index index = new Index();
        String[] titleAndContent = parseFile("files/methode.txt");
        Index index = new Index("files",null);
        try 
        {
            index.openIndex(true);
            index.addDocument(titleAndContent[0], titleAndContent[1], "files/methode.txt");
        } 
        catch (CorruptIndexException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static String[] parseFile(String path)
    {
        String[] titleAndContent = new String[2];
        File file = new File(path);
        try 
        {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(file); 
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); 
            String line = new String();
            String content = new String();
            try 
            {
                while((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
                { 
                     if (line.substring(0,min(6,line.length())).equals("title:"))
                     {
                         titleAndContent[0] = line.substring(6,line.length());
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         if (line.substring(0,min(8,line.length())).equals("content:"))
                         {
                             content += line.substring(8,line.length())+"\n";
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             content += line+"\n";
                         }
                     }
                }
            } 
            catch (IOException e1) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            titleAndContent[1] = content;
            try 
            {
                fr.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return titleAndContent;
    }

    public static int max (int a, int b)
    {
        if (a<b)
        {
            return b;
        }
        return a;
    }

    public static int min (int a, int b)
    {
        if (a<b)
        {
            return a;
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

The problem is, I can't compile my Lucene projet under Eclipse. It keeps telling me:

```
ERROR: index path not specified

Usage: java org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex pathToIndex [-fix] [-segment X] [-segment Y]

  -fix: actually write a new segments_N file, removing any problematic segments
  -segment X: only check the specified segments.  This can be specified multiple
              times, to check more than one segment, eg '-segment _2 -segment _a'.
              You can't use this with the -fix option

**WARNING**: -fix should only be used on an emergency basis as it will cause
documents (perhaps many) to be permanently removed from the index.  Always make
a backup copy of your index before running this!  Do not run this tool on an index
that is actively being written to.  You have been warned!

Run without -fix, this tool will open the index, report version information
and report any exceptions it hits and what action it would take if -fix were
specified.  With -fix, this tool will remove any segments that have issues and
write a new segments_N file.  This means all documents contained in the affected
segments will be removed.

This tool exits with exit code 1 if the index cannot be opened or has any
corruption, else 0.
```

I tried **everything** to make it work, and as the whole web says, I used

```
-ea:org.apache.lucene... pathToIndex -fix
```

as argument of compilation. But whatever I put instead of pathToIndex, it keeps telling me

```
Unexpected argument pathToIndex (or whatever instead)
```

How can I get this f... project work?
Thank you in advance.

Edit: Of course I've imported all Lucene JARs.

Comment: From what you have posted, it looks like you are launching `CheckIndex` class from Lucene itself. Can you show your compilation command (I'm not an Eclipse guy but there has to be a way to see all `javac` parameters)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I started the project over by creating a simple Main class and a main method inside it and tried to compile it immediately. And it worked fine, this time. Note you should show the Main class on your screen tab before compiling in Eclipse.